# Images on server visible in Firefox/Chrome/Opera but not IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, image

I'm developing a website and certain images will not display when returned to IE browser. It will not display both within the returned html page it is contained in and when you link directly to the image. Here is the page the image is contained in:

vrn.vanderbilt.edu/2010

and here is a direct link to the image:

vrn.vanderbilt.edu/2010/Images/may2010s.jpg

Incidentally, there are several other images (vrn.vanderbilt.edu/2010/Images/may2010.jpg) in the folder that are not working in IE as well. This leads me to think that it is a path issue or a server issue.

I don't have any server information as I do not run the server. It is a Vanderbilt server run by a web development department. However, there are two (mostly) identical folders in the root folder "2009" and "2010." Both folders contain an "Images" folder but only the contents of the "Images" folder within "2010" has this issue of not displaying in IE. Images in the 2009 folder work properly in all browsers tested. (vrn.vanderbilt.edu/2009/Images/may2009s.jpg)

Any thoughts or ideas? Does this sound familiar to anyone? Any questions I can answer to help you help me? Sorry about the lack of links. Site won't let me post them as a new user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That picture/s have embedded color profile which IE is unable to display (that's not odd :))..
You need to discard it.

http://pokit.etf.ba/upload/pokit936bc6fd776ce64da2a129ebba5d27d8.png

Comment: Open up in PS, discard profile if any, go to Image > Mode > RGB (instead of CMYK), File > Save As > Level 8 > OK, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Having downloaded this file, it doesn't open up in IE when loaded locally, so it's not a path issue.  It opens in MS Paint, the MS Picture Browser and Photoshop without incident - however, I suspect there's either something not quite right with the image as far as IE is concerned, or IE has a subtle bug in its image rendering.

Comment: Thank you. Would you suggest resaving it in Photoshop?

Answer (score 0):

Also it is in CMYK, but needs to be in RGB to be compatible.
Here's your picture (displays fine in IE): http://j.imagehost.org/0022/may2010s_2.jpg