# IE not displaying pictures

Tags: html, internet-explorer, image

Some certain pictures will not display on my website in IE (I think version 6 through 8). Instead of the picture is simply a box with a red X in it.

- The pictures exist on the server.
- The link isn't broken and it's written in proper XHTML/HTML.
- If you enter the URL to the picture(s) manually you don't get a 404 but simply nothing at all.
- The pictures show up in other browsers.
- The file names and links are all in lower case.
- The pictures are all saved as .jpg.

What's wrong?

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: Provide the broken examples in a JSFiddle. Ares you sure it's not a caching issue?

Comment: Code is nothing special at all. My pictures are within `div` tags, like this.
<div class="ruta1">
<img src="pic1.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
<img src="pic2.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
<img src="pic3.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
</div>
In this example the second picture won't show but the other two will.

Comment: I do not know if it's a caching issue or not. If it isn't is there any other possible explanation or should I just go with cache? :p

Comment: If you use IE's Developer Tools, you should be able to see the request go out to the server to fetch each picture. Is there anything funky in there?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518306/images-on-server-visible-in-firefox-chrome-opera-but-not-ie

Answer (score 0):

It's most probably not a caching issue, since if it were, the old image would have been displayed, instead of no image (excluding the edge case where the cache is registered but the actual file was deleted).

Either way, IE is known for its quirks. Your best bet is to delete all temporary data and refresh.

An extremely wild guess would be that the images were saved using a JPEG compression format unknown to IE; but that is *highly* unlikely.